# json api server query

Tags: java, android, json

I'm building an app that request a json data from the website directly from the app and I'm wondering if there a solution where I download the json data to a server and make the apps do the json request to that server

Comment: you want to only test how to handle json data from server.

Comment: or you have any specific server to get json response.

Comment: I was searching the web and most sites recommend a sql server so I'm going with it , to be honest I don't know if it's the best solution since I have no experience dealing with servers